# Firebase get specific data without Brute Force in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, firebase

i am having some issues with my app.
When i click on a listview item (Which retrieves data from my firebase database) I am starting a new activity with all the information not shown in the Item.
The problem is that I want to send a Bitmap encoded in base 64, and the bundle maximum size is 1 MB.
So I want to get this large String inside the new activity.
Is there a way to directly get this String without reading all the database?
Maybe adding a listener to a ref with the timestamp as child. So is there a way to get this timestamp?

Comment: There definitely is a way to load only specific data from Firebase. But without seeing the minimal code that reproduces your problem, it will be impossible to help.

Comment: I'm not having a problem really. I created a global class where i keep my large string, and then, when the new activity is started, i decode it. But i read in some post that its not recommendabe doing this.